# Using PC and e-piano as audio input for headset while still using built-in microphone

Tags: digital-piano, computer, headphones

I want to use my PC and my piano as audio sources but I still want to be able to use my built-in microphone for voice-chat as an example on the pc.

Now, since I have very little knowledge, to prevent wasting alot of money (~ 76€) I'd really appreciate it if you could look over my thoughts and make suggestions and give advices!

My Thoughts:

1. Buy the [M-Audio 2x2](https://www.amazon.de/M-Audio-Midisport-Anniversary-2-Out-Interface/dp/B001D5D454/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1514545544&sr=8-2&keywords=m%2Baudio%2B2x2&th=1) audio interface
2. Use a [3.5mm (male) to MIDI](https://www.amazon.de/Polig-Stecker-Klinkenstecker-Stereo-Audio/dp/B0053O6CSW/ref=pd_sbs_267_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=WY6TNEVSB217HPE22JPQ) adapter to connect my PC's output to one of the interface's inputs
3. Use another [3.5mm (male) to MIDI](https://www.amazon.de/Polig-Stecker-Klinkenstecker-Stereo-Audio/dp/B0053O6CSW/ref=pd_sbs_267_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=WY6TNEVSB217HPE22JPQ) adapter and a [3.5mm to 6.35mm](https://www.amazon.de/DELOCK-Adapter-Klinke-Stecker-Metall-gold/dp/B008LK005Q/ref=pd_bxgy_23_img_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=VMM40C21T9VG9MWT95SH) adapter (I didn't find any 6.35 (male) to MIDI adapters on amazon) to connect my pianos headphone output to the other interface's input
4. Attach a [3.5mm splitter](https://www.amazon.de/KingTop-Splitter-Adapter-Kopfh%C3%B6rer-Headset-1-Pack/dp/B0177MQ7IW/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1514547966&sr=8-4&keywords=3.5mm%20splitter) to my headset
5. Use a [3.5mm (female) to MIDI](https://www.amazon.de/Tisino-Stecker-Klinke-Stereo-Adapter/dp/B074TXQ19N/ref=pd_day0_23_3?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=RXG1AN8XNRB9F02Y3H0W) adapter to connect my headset's headphone jack with one of the interface's outputs
6. Directly connect the headset's microphone jack (with an [extension cable](https://www.amazon.de/Klinke-Verl%C3%A4ngerung-stereo-Stecker-BUCHSE-Schwarz/dp/B001C568PI/ref=sr_1_3?s=ce-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1514549047&sr=1-3&keywords=3.5mm%20verl%C3%A4ngerung)) to my PC's microphone input

For better visibility I've also sketched everything:
[image: setup]

Do you think this could work and is the cheapest possible way?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Edit: I meant a mixer, I didn't mean an audio interface

Comment: The M-Audio 2x2 is **not** an audio interface. It is a MIDI interface only. MIDI is a digital control signal standard. No audio can be transmitted via MIDI. You cannot plug an audio output or input into a MIDI input or output. It won't work at all. You have to go completely back to the drawing board. No part of your current plan will work. You need an **audio** interface. Your budget may be too small for what you want to do. If you can augment your income somehow, I highly recommend it.

Comment: Well.. yes, but interfacing a mixer with the built-in computer I/O can be very tricky and may not sound great. Ideally a mixer **and** a decent audio interface will give you all kinds of flexibility.